# Issue labeling offset lines

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to draw lines with labels but I need them offset. This is easily done with "line-offset" paint property How can I offset the labels so they line up with the lines?

I've tried using the "text-offset" on the label layer but that unit is in "em" where the label offset is in "pixels".

Working Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hevpqy?file=data%2Flayers.json

Desired Output Example:
[image]

Comment: Try playing with `text-rotate` property

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be caused by the `pitch` you have set: 60.

When pitch is 0, it's fairly easy to find a combination of `text-offset`, `line-width` and `line-offset` that keeps the text within the line:

[image]

But as soon as we tilt the camera:

[image]

I suspect this is a bug or limitation in mapbox-gl-js. You can raise an issue [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues).